# How to return of Called Functions multiple times/NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to return of a function, which also calls a function, but I get a SIGSEV.

MY ASSEMBLER: Linux, Unix nasm 64 +ld

sample:

```
;something
call myFunction

myFunction: 
   call func2
ret

func2:
 ;do sth
ret
```

One possibility is to push the Pointer to the stack, but the Stack is Limited, isn't it? And I need a solution for doing this n-times, whereas n should be able to stand for infinity.

Another possibility is to call the function and do a label for returning, but when I hava a function, which is called by different  routines, I'm runnning into another problem :(

Is there an elegant way of doin' this?

Ox, so I got the suggestion, I should try it as it could work.

I tried it with this code:

```
section .data
    test : db "test", 0x0a; length: 5
    input: db "433", 0x00
    blank: db 0xa

section .bss


section .text
global _start: 
_start:

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h

    mov eax, input
    call strToInt
    mov [input], eax

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, test
    mov edx, 5
    int 80h
    ret

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h;

    strToInt: 
        mov ebx, 0; counter
        mov ecx, 0; ecx is 4 the result
            conversion_loop:
                cmp BYTE[eax], 0 
                jz leave_loop
                sub byte[eax], 48
                inc eax
                inc ebx
                cmp ebx ,9 
                jge leave_loop
                jmp conversion_loop
            leave_loop: 
        call hey        
    ret

    hey:    
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 0
        mov ecx, test
        mov edx, 5
        int 80h
        ret
```

(sorry for the code, this long -.-)

the result is:

```
433test
test
SEGFAULT
```

Does this clarify this a bit?

Comment: ok, with infinitely, I mean, n times. The problem: the register, which stores the pointer to the last call - mnemonics gets refreshed on each new call

Comment: But the return addresses are stored in stack, so the program returns well no matter how many fuction calls are involved.

Comment: really? Gonna retry it. I'll tell you later how it went.

Comment: tried it. Result in question as edit :(

Comment: I think @RomanChe's answer is right, you have a `ret` outside a proc (at the end of your third block of code).

Comment: yup, he was. As said, I'm trying uberman sleep cycle, so I'm pretty dizzy rigth now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this lines:

```
    int 80h
    ret
```

I think this `ret` is jump out of your code segment. You must remove `ret` to call sys_exit function to complete programm gracefully.

Comment: Come on, I'm soooo stupid. maybe it wasn't a good idea to try the uberman sleeping cycle :).